# Increase length of my headset without extra investment

Tags: audio, microphone, wired-networking

My headset which have an inbuilt mic is only 4 feets in length and I would like to increase its length.

The reason is because my desktop cpu is places away underneath the table and I have to bend down or decrease my chair height to use the headset which is uncomfortable.

I can buy an aux cable and a female to female adapter but that is costly now in Amazon due to the pandemic. I am not in a position to spend that much money.

I already have damaged headset of the same brand.

Can I use that wire and solder it to the new headset?

If yes, can you tell me how could I identify the which wire is which for the purpose of soldering.

Thank you very much for replying in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily. But this method is not suggested though because your headset is new and you may damage the headset.

It is better to buy a 3.5mm female to male extender.

But this is the method for your information.

[image]

In this image of the 3.5mm male pin, you can see 4 connection points separated by 3 nonconducting white circles. This means there are 4 wires in this headset.

Since, you said that your headset has mic, your 3.5 pin should have 4 wires.

1. Left channel -Tip
2. Right channel -Ring
3. Ground -Ring
4. Mic -Sleeve
   This is also called TRRS.

[image]

You can cut the old headset from the wire below the division of the headset. We are going to use the 3.5 mm pin of the old headset. I’m hoping that that old headset wires are good.

Then cut the new headset from the 3.5mm pin area. We are not going to use this jack.

Now use a wire stripper or a lighter to strip the wire. Since you have the same brand, connect the same color wires together.

If you are using different brand wires and if the colors are not matching, just play a song, connect the old headset to the pc and do trial and error and you will get it correct in less than 17 tries.

[image]
In the image, you can see 3 wires.

This image is only for your reference. The headset had four wires but I did not need the mic. So I cut off the mic wire.
The headset wires are too thin. So be careful with soldering, if you are attempting.

But I suggest you to buy a headset extender which looks like this. But a TRRS extender. This image shown below is a TRS extender meaning there is no mic with this extender.
[image]

Comment: Male to female sounds interesting Still I don’t want to spend any money on this.Will give ur method a try. Hope its same colors. The headset is not new. Is doing this safe for my pc? Did you use wire cutter and is it easy?

Comment: I will be frank. I really have no idea about the safeness. The voltage and power draw in the wires seems low. But I am no expert in this area. Regarding the wire cutter question, I don’t own a wire cutter and since the wire is too thin, I used flames from a lighter just enough to melt the wire and use my finger nails to scrape the plastic from the steel wire.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I’m glad that I could help. Please do this with caution. I did the testing with my pc front panel. But in case anything goes wrong, your jack might be damaged and maybe your pc. I suggest testing with a cheap mp3 player instead.